# ActiveRecord post error with dropdown box integer value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm going crazy with this. I have a form with a dropdown box

```
<select name="user[interest1]">
<option value="1">Something</option>
<option value="2">Another Something</option>
<option value="3">Another Something^3</option>
</select>
```

Posting this should update the user model with an integer on the field "interest1".
When sending the form I get this error:

```
Interest1(#70226795163000) expected, got String(#70226775629700)

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 ...
 "interest1"=>"3"},
 "commit"=>"Update"}
```

Ok so this is a String that is being posted although it should be an integer.
Easy I thought so I'm going to catch that param in my controller and make it an integer:

```
params[:user][:interest1] = params[:user][:interest1].to_i
```

Now I get this:

```
Interest1(#70226795828040) expected, got Fixnum(#70226775624220)

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 ...
 "interest1"=>3},
 "commit"=>"Update"}
```

Although this is what I actually expect, it won't get updated in my database.
What do I do wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have an Interest1 model that is associated with user and you are trying to assign to that association using the association ID. If this is the case then you want the field to be interest1_id and add that to User's attr_accessible.

If not, then can you please post your User model.

Comment: gotcha. That is indeed the case. How do I tell activerecord now that I want to use the param interest1_id as interest1 when posting the form?

Comment: Change the form so it has `user[interest1_id]` instead of `user[interest1]`. It's not an AR thing, it has to do with the form helpers in your view.

Comment: That worked when I renamed also the column in the model to interest1_id. Was that necessary?

Comment: Yes, it is the foreign key that holds the related Interest1 model's id.